# Config changes to a GAE app without redeploying?

Tags: google-app-engine

Suppose I just want to make a config change to an GAE app (i.e no code changes) - Is there a way change the config file and bounce the GAE instance rather than a full deployment ?

I am using GPE for eclipse.

Regards,

Sathya

Comment: The deployments are actually differential - `appcfg` tool only uploads files that were changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the command appcfg is part of the GAE sdk and will help you to manage you app.